# How to remove the notification badge count in react-native-firebase/messaging after opening the app

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to update the notification count to 0 once the app is opened but I couldn't find any relevant methods to update the badge count in @react-native-firebase/messaging package. Is there any possible way to update the notification count inside the app?

This is my listener

```
messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(async (remoteMessage) => {
    console.log(remoteMessage);
})
```

Are there any methods provided by rnfirebase package to set the badge count inside the app? If there then that would be a great help

Answer (score 1):

I've used the below package to solve this problem

```
react-native-push-notification
```

Here's the code for it,

```
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);
```

This will reset the badge count to 0 once you open the app, You can also set the count as you want dynamically and it will get updated.

Answer (score 0):

import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

using code:
firebase.notifications().removeAllDeliveredNotifications();
or:
firebase.notifications().removeDeliveredNotification(notificationId);